# Resharper Code Pattern for IDisposable not inside using

Tags: resharper, static-analysis

I'd like to know how to build a Resharper (6.1) code pattern to search and replace the following issues:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and turn it into this:

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
  cmd.ExecuteNotQuery();
}
```

**and:**

```
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("myfile.txt");
 string line = reader.Read();
 Console.WriteLine(line);
```

becomes:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
{
   string line = reader.ReadLine();
   Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

**EDIT:** *Thanks for the answers, but I'm looking for anything that implements `IDisposable`*

Answer (score 2):

Search pattern:

```
var $cmd$ = $sqlcommand$;
$cmd$.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Replace pattern:

```
using (var $cmd$ = $sqlcommand$)
{
$cmd$.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

where `cmd` = identifier

and `sqlcommand` = expression of type `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand`

Comment: Close but exclusive to SqlCommand problems.  I'm looking for opportunities to use `using` in the codebase.

Comment: Um.. Your original question was _exactly_ SqlCommand-specific

Comment: You are correct, but the title has not changed.  I made the edit to clarify my question.  I also up-voted your response, however it is not the answer I was looking for.  Is there no way to use code patterns to find an object implementing `IDisposable` that isn't wrapped with `using`?

Comment: As far as I understand, code patterns are not powerful enough to do this, particularly because they won't let you negate conditions (find code implementing IDisposable that is _not_ inside _using_). In the scope of ReSharper toolset, this is only possible by writing a ReSharper plug-in as Dmitri suggests.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you're really after is an inspection mechanism that goes off looking for `IDisposable` objects and ensures they are disposed. If that's the case, I doubt custom patterns would be the right approach - after all, what if you *do* call `Dispose()` a few lines later?

One way to implement this is by using the [ReSharper SDK](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/index.html). In fact, one of the examples the SDK comes with is a PowerToy which implements `IDisposable` on a particular class, so you could take that code as a foundation for possible analysis of usage.

Comment: Calling Dispose a few lines later won't help if an exception gets thrown on one of the other lines, unless you call it from a finally block.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Search with Pattern tool under the ReSharper | Find menu.

In the Search pattern make sure you have C# selected and enter the code you're searching for in the box.  Click the Replace button in the top-right, and enter the code you want to replace it with in the Replace pattern box.

You can save the search and replace pattern and R# will use it for subsequent code analysis should you so desire.  You can also add additional patterns in R# Options under Code Inspection | Custom Patterns.

Comment: Nice detail/approach, but I'm looking for the code pattern catalog snippet here

Comment: Are you talking about adding a Custom Pattern in Code Inspection?

Comment: Yes, Custom Pattern and ANYTHING that implements `IDisposable`